# In Google Sheets, How Do You Order a Query by row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-query-language

I am trying to make a query and drop it into a table (really only a 5x5 grid of boxes with a black border color), but I want it to be ordered by row instead of column. I currently have the formula `=QUERY(B14:J14)` and I tried to make it `=QUERY(B14:J15,"order by 15")` but an error message came up because you can't use order to order by the row. Can someone please tell me if there is a way to make the query order by row number instead of by the column letter?

Comment: I suspect you can do this, by rotating it twice. Not sure what the function is, I would ask on the "google spreadsheet forum".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eddyparkinson is correct, just need to "double transpose".

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B14:J15),"order by Col2"))`

Comment: Thanks, Adam. This helped me a lot. But, I believe that you need to switch `Col2` to `Col1`.That's what I did because an error message came up saying there was no `Col2`

Comment: Wait. . . I realized that now, it orders reverse the way I want to make it order. Is there any way I can make it order the other way, or transpose it 2 more times?

Comment: There will be no Col2 I'd there is only one row (one of your examples suggested there were 2 rows). If you want sort descending, use "order by Col1 desc".

Comment: Thanks! That will help me a lot in the future, since I was previously making it go the other way, which was really bad! :-)